# Mac Cannot Access Any App or System Preference

Tags: macos, mac

I cannot access any application or any of the System Preference (including terminal, Disk utility, etc.).
This happened as a mistake of `sudo` action. What can I do now?[image]

Comment: What was done with the `sodu` command? Knowing that would make the problem easier to diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I diagnosed and found out the following solution as a reference to future users.

1. Shut Down your PC
2. Hold Down `Cmd` + `R` with power button
3. Click on Disk Utility
4. Select your Mac Disk and CLick on `Repair Disk Permissions`
5. Chill Out!